# Groovy: Dynamic Method Invocation and their parameters

Tags: java, dynamic, groovy

Yesterday I started with using Groovy and I found out the  [Dynamic Method Invocation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Dynamic+Groovy)  function. This is a nice function to call methods dynamically based on their method name.  And this is working fine for me. Now we would like to call these methods based on their name with different parameters. For example I have 2 mehods:

```
 def changeResponseWithParametersAandB(def response, String a, String b) { 
        response.result = args[0];
        return response;
 }

 def changeResponseWithParameterA(def response, String a) { 
        response.result = args[0];
        return response;
 }
```

I will loop trough a list with the method names, like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < methods.size(); i++) {
    DynamicMethods dynamicMethod = methods.get(i);
    methodName = dynamicMethod.getMethodName();

    changeFieldValues."$methodName"(response, <HOW_SHOULD_I_DO_THIS_PART>);
}
```

The only problem is that this won’t work for one of the two methods. I should use for the first method 2 parameters and for the second method 3 parameters. Is there a way to solve this issue in groovy? Or should I just use a map/array or something like that?

Thanks for you answer!

Comment: In the for loop, where do you get the parameters to pass to the dynamic methods?

Answer (score 7):

Something like below would suffice? Instead of having two methods you can have one method with the second argument optional. I tried to mimic the implementation by maps and lists. Shout out if you need more clarifications.

```
def changeResponseWithParametersAandB(def response, String a, String b = null) { 
    response.result = [first: a, second: b]
    return response
}

def methods = [ 'changeResponseWithParametersAandB' ]
def response = [:]
def args = [ [ 'string1' ], [ 'string1', 'string2' ] ]

args.each { arg ->
    methods.each { method ->
        def result = "$method"( response, *arg )
        assert arg.size() == 1 ? 
            result == [ result : [ first:'string1', second:null ] ] : 
            result == [ result : [ first:'string1', second:'string2' ] ]
    } 
}

return "Done testing"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. This answer is using arrays, and that is not exactly what I had in mind. I changed my code and now I'm using Maps. I think this would make the code more 'understandable', because you sees what argument you will use by map.get("KEY"). But thanks for you answer, I think it could still be usefull for other people.

Comment: I think using a map and then doing map[method] or a list and going by index (or use each) is not too much of a difference. The keypoint is to use the spread operator in "$method"(response, *arg)

Comment: Yes. This answer is mainly focused on the use of the spread operator for arguments and the use of optional argument to the method. You can have whichever implementation for collecting args and methods, you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can pack the parameters in a list and use `as Object[]` to pass them. I find `invokeMethod` slightly cleaner, but it is a matter of taste:

```
def foo(number, string) { number + string }
def bar(number) { number * 2 }

def calls = [foo: [90, 'string'], bar: [150]].collect { method, params ->
  this.invokeMethod(method, params as Object[])
}

assert calls[0] == '90string'
assert calls[1] == 300
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. This answer is using arrays, and that is not exactly what I had in mind. I changed my code and now I'm using Maps. I think this would make the code more 'understandable', because you sees what argument you will use by map.get("KEY"). But thanks for you answer, I think it could still be usefull for other people.

Comment: @Gynnad Even though the parameters are passed as an array, they are still acessible inside the method through the parameters `a` and `b`.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I think this is one of the best solutions. Only this is not working for us. Thanks for your answer and time!